# add(float x, int pos) in a list (linked)

Tags: c#

I've been asked to implement the function `MyList` (even though it already exists by default in C#).

I managed to do a good part of the code but I'm stuck on the final function (I tried to solve it in 2 different ways that I'll show down below, and that obviously didn't work).

He want us for the final function to do this:

```
public void add(float x, int pos)
{
  // Add x at the position pos, pos = 0 refer to the first element.
}
```

I tried to solve it like this at first:

```
if (pos == 0)
{
    add(x);
}
else
{
    for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
        {
            add(x);
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried here is that I'll do a double for loop so that the pointer will be at the same place as the position `pos` and then I'll add the `float x` at that position.

But it didn't work. The output for this following main() was:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyList l = new MyList();
        l.add(0);
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(4);
        l.add(5);
        l.add(6);
        l.add(109, 2);
        l.print();
    }
```

Output:

```
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
109
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

So I tried it in a different way:

```
if (pos == 0)
{
    add(x);
}
else
{
    int count = 0;
    for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == pos)
        {
            add(x);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried here is completely different. I implemented `count` so that when `count` is equal to `pos`, the pointer will be at the `pos` position and then I'll be able to add the `float x` to that position. But it also didn't work. For the same previous main() this was the output:

```
109
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

The problem here is that no matter what the position `pos` is. The number 109 will stay at it's place.

Here you will found everything I've done (except for the `add(float x, int pos)` function, which I need your help to solve):

```
public class MyList
{
    class Element
    {
        public float value;
        public Element next;
    }

    Element first;

    public MyList()
    {
        first = null;
    }

    public void add(float x)
    {
        Element e = new Element();
        e.value = x;
        e.next = first;
        first = e;
    }
    public float get(int i)
    {
        if (first == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Empty list... no elements inside");
        }

        Element tmp = first;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            tmp = tmp.next;
            if (tmp == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("...");
            }
        }
        return tmp.value;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        Element e = first;
        while (e != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.value);
            e = e.next;
        }
    }

    public bool find(float x)
    {
        Element e = first;
        while (e != null)
        {
            if (e.value == x)
            {
                return true;
            }
            e = e.next;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public float max()
    {
        float G = 0;
        for (Element e = first; e != null; e = e.next)
        {
            if (e.value > G)
            {
                G = e.value;
            }
        }
        return G;
    }

    public int count()
    {
        Element e = first;
        int c = 0;
        while (e != null)
        {
            c++;
            e = e.next;
        }
        return c;
    }

    public int count(float x)
    {
        int c = 0;
        for (Element e = first; e != null; e = e.next)
        {
            if (e.value == x)
            {
                c++;
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public float sum()
    {
        float S = 0;
        for (Element e = first; e != null; e = e.next)
        {
            S += e.value;
        }
        return S;
    }

    public float average()
    {
        return sum() / count();
    }

    public void removeFirst()
    {
        Element e = first;
        first = e.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "didn't work" and provide a [mcve].

Comment: your question is appropriate, since you are providing code you wrote yourself in an attempt to solve the problem. But to get good answers, please reduce your question to a minimal example. The evolution is not relevant IMO. add sample input and expected output, and information where the error/exception/wrong data appears. And make yourself familiar with the debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'll edit it and show were it didn't work.

Comment: I just added what my outputs were so that you can see more clearly what my problem is. If you need any other clarifications. Please tell me. And I'm sorry. But I don't see how I can reduce the question without missing some major points :/

Comment: forgive me if I was not very clear. I study programming in french so we're used to call the code that implements a declaration like public void add(float x, int pos) a fonction.

Comment: I am talking about the "I tried to solve it like this at first" chapter. That can be omitted, IMO it adds nothing useful.
the actual problem is the `e.next = first` part. it causes new elements to be inserted in the first position always. you will need to "splice" the list in order to insert at any given (and valid) position.

Comment: Here's a tip.  as your code is, `add(x);` always adds `x` to the beginning of the list.  regardless of whether you call it from within a `for` loop or not

Comment: analogy: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4c/40/dd/4c40dd450f4187d2f92f6e7e26ae725d.jpg the trunks are the `next` pointers. the leftmost is `first`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (pos == 0)
{
    add(x);
}
else
{
    int count = 0;
    for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == pos)
        {
            add(x); // this always adds the element to the beginning
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The thing about it is that `add(x)` does the same thing regardless where in the code you use it. You have to manually insert the element into the position.

```
int count = 0;
for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
{
    count++;
    if(count == pos)
    {
        var newElem = new Element();
        newElem.value = x;
        newElem.next = tmp.next;
        tmp.next = newElem;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You're right I didn't realize that I was always adding the element to the first of the list and not to the position were the pointer is ! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that within the `if(count == pos)` you are calling `add(x)` which always adds `x` at the beginning of the list.

Insead, your `add(float x, int pox)` *method* should look like this:

```
if (pos == 0)
{
    add(x);
}
else
{
    int count = 0;
    for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == pos)
        {
            Element e = new Element();
            e.value = x;
            e.next = tmp.next;
            tmp.next = e;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
> {
>     for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++)
>     {
>         add(x);
>     }
> }
> ```

In your first attempt, you are adding the value `x` as many time as `pos` after every element in the list. Also, since the adding break the links and pushes the first element to the last. You get the result: [`x` repeated `pos` times] with `initial first value` at the end.

> ```
> int count = 0;
> for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
> {
>     count++;
>     if(count == pos)
>     {
>         add(x);
>         break;
>     }
> }
> ```

In your send attempt, you did the right loop to find where to insert the value. However, you added the value directly to the top on the link-list without using the `tmp` location which you just found out.

---

So, you just need to change a bit the 2nd method to **insert** the value after the `tmp`:

```
for (Element tmp = first; tmp != null; tmp = tmp.next)
{
    count++;
    if(count == pos)
    {
        tmp.next = new Element { value = x, next = tmp.next };
        break;
    }
}
```